# Exporting/copying data from PDF to Excel and aligning the columns and rows together

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

In real estate, I usually have to manually write each tenant and their information into our models. We usually get PDFs and not excel spreadsheets. There are two problems that happens a lot if I try to export PDF using Adobe standard. Photo 1 is where I hold CTRL and copied everything over, except I have to manually move over the data into the same column then I concatenate the data so I can then finish by copy pasting it into my spreadsheet.

[image: Photo of Copied data]

The other way is using the exported PDF data and manually working around it. When there's 50 tenants, it can take me all day.

[image: Raw exported from PDF to excel]

Does anyone have solutions I can use? I feel like i'm wasting so much time. Any VBA solutions or creative exporting solutions using adobe standard?

In the end, I need a column for Tenant Names, the square footage, the base rent, the rent per SF, the lease start date, end date. As you can see, the data gets thrown all over the place.

Comment: Are you saying you get tenant data in PDF format and you need to enter that manually into an excel model? The problem is that there is no guaranteed 'fields' in a PDF. If you wanted to automate extracting data in PDF then it's only worth it if most of your data arrives in an identically formatted PDF document, and you know this format is not gong to change in the near future. The key is this: You need to be able to consistently identify fields in the PDF document. If you can do that you can automate it.

Comment: The data in your second screenshot actually looks like something you could work with to automate but first it's worth investigating if this can actually be sent to you in excel format to begin with (as this would come out of someones database). In your second screenshot where is the tenant name? Also how comfortable are you with VBA?